# Mouse Click alone takes precedence over "Regular Key Pressed as Modifier"+ Mouse Click

Tags: interface, customization

I'm trying to setup my hotkeys so I can more easily sculpt with a tablet. As a part of this I tried to change the hotkeys for invert and smooth sculpting. By default this is done using normal modifier keys, in this case control or shift + left click. This works. But I wanted to use a regular key as modifier, A and S in my case.

So under Blender User Preferences > Input. Then 3D View > Sculpt there are three Sculpt options: Regular, Inverted and Smooth. There's a bunch of normal modifier keys, but there's a blank field where you can enter 'Regular keys as modifier'. But when I changed the settings for invert and smooth to A+Left Click and S+Left Click and tried this, they both only did regular sculpting. After fiddling with it for a bit I noticed it's not that the hotkey doesn't work, but that the left click sends you into regular sculpt mode regardless of what regular-key-modifier you press. You can notice this when you disable the regular sculpting tool (the one that only uses left click).

I assumed the regular key as modifier should work similar to the normal modifiers, but it seemed not to.

Is this a bug? Can someone reproduce this? Can someone help? I would really like to use a regular key and not control/shift/alt for this.
Thanks :)

PS. In sculpt mode S is linked to the smooth brush, so you need to disable this hotkey if you want to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DerekWatts over at BlenderArtists answered my question in [this](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?405598-Input-Keybindings-quot-Regular-key-pressed-as-modifier-quot-not-working-as-intended) topic.

Apparently it's a known issue and it's fixable by changing the order in which they appear in the hotkey list. Disabling the original left-click-only hotkey and add a duplicate at the bottom of the list fixes it.